# Inject into Activity using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, wear-os, dagger-hilt

How can I inject a retrofit instance in a class that extends Activity instead of AppCompatActivity?
This is the Module:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object Module {
    private const val BASE_URL = "API_URL_HERE"

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitApi(): Api {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(Api::class.java)
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : Activity() {
    ...
    @Inject
    lateinit var api: Api
    ...
```

This results in

Activities annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint must be a subclass of androidx.activity.ComponentActivity. (e.g. FragmentActivity, AppCompatActivity, etc.)
[Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.

I tried using *@ActivityScoped* instead of *@AndroidEntryPoint* but it results in

kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property api has not been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to decorate your module with `@Module` annotation.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object Module {
    private const val BASE_URL = "API_URL_HERE"

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitApi(): Api {
         return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(Api::class.java)
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Why not extend ComponentActivity? This is a known requirement of Hilt.

But if you really can't, then create an entry point using the @EntryPoint annotation.

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported

```
    val hiltEntryPoint =
      EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(appContext, ExampleContentProviderEntryPoint::class.java)

    val analyticsService = hiltEntryPoint.analyticsService()
```

Call it from you activity onCreate,

Comment: If I need to extend from com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity, for example, and I don't have control over what that extends.